# What is the difference between a distribution and a process (Poisson)?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, terminology, stochastic-processes, weibull-distribution

I'm doing my PhD in geomechanics. I thought we use a Poisson-Weibull distribution (for the variability of a parameter at the rock), but reading more about the subject I think maybe is a Poisson-Weibull process and I don't know the difference. To complete the problem I'm not too knowledgeable about the language of mathematics, so if you could give me an example it would be awesome!

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [stochastic processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process) provides a clear, succinct, non-mathematical answer on the first line and right next to it is a picture of data that are typically thought of as resulting from a process.  Have you investigated these materials?

Comment: A Poisson process is a model for a "real world" process that generates events in time. It has many distributions associated with it depending on what aspects of it you consider (e.g. the distribution of event-times in a fixed window is uniform, the distribution of time between events is exponential, the distribution of the number of events in a time interval is Poisson, etc).

Comment: Both of the comments could be considered answers, albeit brief answers.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the answers! I have read the wikipedia article, but I think I have a more elementary problem to understand what real means "process" or even "distribution". I know the format of an exponetial distribution, or uniform, or Poisson, but I have a problem on understanding what this really means! I know that on a normal distribution we have a little chance to find events really "small" or really "big".
I'm sorry, I'm sure your answers are good, but I still need a simpler explanation. 
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 13):

- [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) = a specific  [discrete probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution), i.e. a  [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) characterized by a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function). Specifically, in the case of Poisson, it is defined as $P(k \text{ events in interval}) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R^+}, k \in \mathbb{N}$.
- [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) = a  [stochastic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stochastic_process&oldid=728198050), i.e.  a collection of random variables representing the evolution of some system of random values over time. In [other words](http://www.scholarpedia.org/w/index.php?title=Law_of_series/Stochastic_process&oldid=127582),  it is a family of real random variables $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)\ ,$ where the set T is interpreted as ''time''. Specifically, a *Poisson* process [can be defined in different ways](https://www.netlab.tkk.fi/opetus/s38143/luennot/E_poisson.pdf), not necessarily using the Poisson distribution:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A random process is a sequence of random variables. That means, when talking about a process, e.g. Poisson process, an element of occurrences as a sequence in time is involved, while when we talk about random variables and their distribution, e.g. Poisson distribution, there is no such element involved, and we only have a random variable X with its associated distribution.

Example:

Random variable X: the number of phone calls to a receptionist per hour follows the Poisson distribution (and with the distribution known we can have the probability of receiving a certain number of phone calls in a given time interval);

Random process {X1, X2, ....}, where Xi: the time when the ith phone call was received, is a Poisson process.

Comment: How does the Poisson process compare to the Gaussian process? (aka are kernels and conditioning methods used to infer what $y_i$ an unobserved $x_i$ might take on?)